# MultipartFile inside Custom Request / Response Objects

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-resttemplate

Can we send MultipartFile inside a Custom Request Object in a Rest Template call? Similarly, can we receive a MutlipartFile inside a Custom Response Object returned from a Rest call made through the Rest Template?

Basically, we need to send other essential attributes along with a File Upload and receive few attributes along with a File Download.

Is this possible through a Spring Rest Template?

Below is the Code,

```
public class UploadRequest {    
    private Long checkSum;    
    private MultiPartFile fileContents; 
    //setters and getters  
}
```

We receive the MultipartFile from a controller end point, we just relay it to
another endpoint using the below is the Rest template call,

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
headers.setContentType("mutipart/form-data");  
  
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new MultiValueMap<>();  
map.add("uploadRequest", uploadRequest);  
  
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);  
  
ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uploadUrl, requestEntity, UploadResponse.class);
```

it results in the below exception,

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException No Serializer for class java.io.FileDescriptor
```

and

```
no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Spring has a class that handles Multipart files - `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`. You can use it to send or receive multipart files. But the request body needs to be `form-data`. You can not send file over `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Just use `MultipartFile` as an attribure in your custom request and you sould be good to go.

```
@Component
public class CustomRequest {
    ...
    private Long checkSum;
    private MultipartFile file;
    ...
    // make sure you have the getters and setters right
    // also the filed names are spelled exactly the same as they are in the form
    // for example myFile and my_file are different
    
    public MultiValueMap<String, String> getRequestBody() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        requestBody.add("checkSum", this.getCheckSum());
        requestBody.add("fileContents", this.getFileContents());
        // add other fileds if you need

        return requestBody;
    }
}
```

In the controller,

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
headers.setContentType("mutipart/form-data");    
  
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(customRequest.getRequestBody(), headers);  
  
ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uploadUrl, requestEntity, UploadResponse.class);
```

What happened was that you were sending the request body inside the `MultiValueMap`. You have to send the form data inside the `MultiValueMap`. And make sure your response has the getters and setters. Spring needs getter setter to serialize the object.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response!  When we try to make the rest call through the Spring Rest Template, by constructing a CustomRequest like mentioned above, we get an error stating No Bean Serializer Found. Please note, the request  header included the Content Type value as multipart/form-data. Are we missing something?

Comment: It’s hard to troubleshoot something without looking at the error. Can you please give the codes for your custom request?

Comment: I updated my answer based on the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, it helped us move forward!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We made the following changes to finally get it working,

1. We changed the RestController endpoints attribute annotations, we had the `@RequestBody` annotation for the attribute `UploadRequest`, we had to change it to `@ModelAttribute` as per the suggestions in [content-type-multipart-form-databoundary-charset-utf-8-not-supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051177/content-type-multipart-form-databoundary-charset-utf-8-not-supported/56789544) This helped us overcome the Http Error 415 - UnsupportedMediaType.
2. On the Client Side, we introduce the class `FileSystemResource` as per the suggestions in [Rest Api Call over Rest Template with MultipartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152337/rest-api-call-other-rest-api-in-spring-boot-not-working-for-multipart-file)

```
public static class FileSystemResource extends ByteArrayResource {

    private String fileName;

    public FileSystemResource(byte[] byteArray , String filename) {
        super(byteArray);
        this.fileName = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename() { return fileName; }
    public void setFilename(String fileName) { this.fileName= fileName; }

}
```

then changed the rest call as below,

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
headers.setContentType("mutipart/form-data");  
  
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new MultiValueMap<>();  
map.add("checkSum", request.getCheckSum());
map.add("fileContents", new FileSystemResource(request.getFile().getBytes(), request.getFile().getOriginalFileName()));
  
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);  
  
ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uploadUrl, requestEntity, UploadResponse.class);
```

after these changes, it worked.